# PHP - BLOB not inserting into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I'm trying to create a page where someone can upload a document or image and it will be stored in the MySQL database, however, for some reason the content of the documents/images aren't actually being insert in to the table I created. Oddly, the rest of the columns within the table are getting populated, it's only the one `LONGBLOB` column that is not.

Here is the HTML code for the form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
        <label>Select Event:</label>
           <select name="eventID">
              <?php
                 foreach($data as $e)
                 {
                     echo "<option value='" . $e["eventID"] . "'>" . $e["name"] . "</option>";
                 }
              ?>
          </select>

          <label>Your ID:</label>

          <input name="contributorID" type="number" min="0" />

          <label>Your Abstract:</label>

          <textarea name="abstract" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

          <label>Attachment:</label>

          <input type="file" name="attachment" />

</form>
```

I believe my form is correct, and ensured that both the hidden field with the max value exists and the encoding is correct.

This is the PHP code that handles the POST of the form:

```
$abstract = $this->model("Abstracts");

if (!empty($_FILES["attachment"]) && ($_FILES["attachment"]["error"] == 0))
{
    $fileName = $_FILES["attachment"]['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES["attachment"]['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES["attachment"]['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES["attachment"]['type'];

    //$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = file_get_contents($tmpName);
    $content = addslashes($content);
    //fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
       $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    $abstract->insertAbstract($_POST["contributorID"], $_POST["eventID"], $_POST["abstract"], $content, $fileName, $fileType, $fileSize);
}
```

The `insertAbstract` method of the `Abstracts` class:

```
public function insertAbstract($contributorID, $eventID, $abstract, $attachment = null, $name = null, $type = null, $size = null)
{
    $conn = new Credentials;
    $this->connection = $conn->conn;

    if (!empty($attachment))
    {
        $query = $this->connection->prepare("CALL sp_PopulateAbstractAttachments(?,?,?,?,?)");
        $query->bind_param("ibssi", $abstractID, $attachment, $name, $type, $size);

        $query->execute();

        $query->close();
    }

    mysqli_close($this->connection);
}
```

The SQL behind the Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROC...
(abID INT, att LONGBLOB, n VARCHAR(500), t VARCHAR(30), s INT)
BEGIN
    DELETE
    FROM abstractattachments
    WHERE abstractID = abID;

    INSERT INTO abstractattachments
    (abstractID, attachment, name, type, size)
    VALUES (abID, att, n, t, s);
END
```

The row inserts with the correct `abID`, `n`, `t`, `s`, but `attn` doesn't seem to. In phpMyAdmin, this value is just empty in the table. Correct me if I'm wrong, but should it not show a value? Just to double check if I'm right, I created a script to download a file but when I open the file it comes up as an empty file.

Here is the script:

```
public function downloadAbstract()
{
   //instantiates connection object from credentials.php
   $conn = new Credentials;
   $this->connection = $conn->conn;

   //manually change attachmentID parameter for script
   $query = "SELECT name, type, size, attachment FROM AbstractAttachments WHERE attachmentID = 22";

   $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
   list($name, $type, $size, $attachment) = mysqli_fetch_array($this->result);

   header("Content-length: $size");
   header("Content-type: $type");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
   echo $attachment;

   mysqli_close($this->connection);
   exit;
}
```

I'm at a lost here, so any guidance will be welcomed. I've tried to condense the code as much as I could.

Comment: It will be corrupt because you're using `addslashes()`. No need to do that, since the parameterized query takes care of escaping. No idea what PMA's behaviour is for blob columns. If you want to verify stuff you'd be better off skipping it and just going into the MySQL console directly.

Comment: @miken32 I commented that line out however it still doesn't work. Strange.

Comment: What is `$abstractID`? And does your download code give you a corrupt file or an empty one? Also you've got a spelling error in your procedure: `DELIMETER`

Comment: It's a foreign key to the table `Abstract`, this is retrieved from a different query when the form is submitted and is inserted correctly into the `AbstractAttachments` table. And a empty file. That's just my mistake when writing the post, the procedure did compile correctly, I'll edit it out.

Comment: Ok I'd expect to see it passed to `insertAbstract()` from outside is why I asked. Any update on corrupt vs empty?

Comment: It's definitely an empty file every time I download it. In the table the `size` column shows a large value.

Comment: Ok only other thing I can suggest is check for [errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and [warnings](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-warnings.php) (which you should be doing anyway!)

Comment: Also try `SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(attachment) FROM AbstractAttachments` which will show you the size of the blobs. You have updated your download script to download a different file that wasn't addslash'd?

Comment: The `OCTET_LENGTH` returns 0, so there is something definitely wrong somewhere. I did do a `var_dump` of `$attachment` and my application shows a whole load of random characters, so something somewhere is not right. I will keep digging around.

Comment: I suspect `get_warnings()` will give you the answer then.

Comment: Through phpMyAdmin, I manually inserted the document I was trying to insert from my application, and it threw an error saying `#2006 - MySQL server has gone away`, along with the query it tried to execute and actually showing a value for the attachment column.

Comment: Try `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';` if that's not set big enough it will cause that problem.

Comment: Okay, so the file I'm uploading is bigger than the max packet value, so that's one problem. However, when I manually uploaded a small image, it worked fine, but from my application nothing. So there is something wrong with my PHP code, as well as the max packet value being allowed to send.

Comment: So small files are storing in your database successfully?

Comment: Yes, when manually uploaded through phpMyAdmin

Comment: But not through your page? Then you're back to checking warnings. I'm going to post an answer with my suggestions so far. Consider saving your files to a folder instead!

Comment: I might have to do that, thank you for your assistance so far.

Comment: No problem. Good luck and merry Christmas!

Comment: You too mate and a happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at using sql procedures, try the following code after creating the table in mysql database  and it will work
. Please mark this as correct answer if it really solve your problem...

### sql

```
create table customer_account (photo_id int(55) primary key auto_increment,photo longblob,name varchar(88),account_no integer(86),address varchar(72),email varchar(45));
```

### html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <font color=green size=4>upload Passport Photograph of aCustomer<BR>
    Using PHP Uploads Technology</font></b><br>     
    <form method="post" action="upload.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <table class="main">
        <tr>
          <td class="header" colspan="2">General Account Opening Form Along with Passport Photograph of the Customer<BR>
            Using PHP Uploads Technology
          </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
          <td>Photo</td>
          <td><input type="file" name="photo_upload" class="long"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" class="long"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Account Number</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="account_no" class="long"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address</td>
          <td><input name="address" type="text"></td>
        <tr>
           <td>Email</td>
            <td><input name="email" type="TEXT"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Register!" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body> 
</html>
```

### upload.php

```
<?
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "nickolysis_username", "nick_password", "photo_database");

$photo_upload='';// variable photo is set to photo_upload
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$account_no=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['account_no']);
$address=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

// read image with variable read_customerphoto and then insert into database    
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo_upload']['tmp_name'],"customerphoto.img");
        $read_customerphoto = fopen("customerphoto.img","rb");
        $photo = addslashes(fread($read_customerphoto,filesize("customerphoto.img")));

if($stmt->prepare("insert into customer_account(photo,name,account_no,address,email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
  $photo_id= mysql_insert_id();
  $stmt->bind_param('ssiss',$photo,$name,$account_no,$address,$email);
  $stmt->execute();

  // Close statement object
  $stmt->close();
  print "<font size=4 color=green>upload is successful</font> ";
}
else{
  print "error";
}
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Copying and pasting unrelated code is not providing an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

First, your stored files could be corrupted by using `addslashes()`. You don't want to do that, since [the parameterized query takes care of escaping](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

> Bound variables are sent to the server separately from the query and thus cannot interfere with it. The server uses these values directly at the point of execution, after the statement template is parsed. **Bound parameters do not need to be escaped as they are never substituted into the query string directly.** A hint must be provided to the server for the type of bound variable, to create an appropriate conversion.

Another issue we figured out in comments, your database was not configured to allow such large parameters to be passed to it. You can try using [`send_long_data()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php) to pass the parameter to the database in smaller chunks.

```
    $query = $this->connection->prepare("CALL sp_PopulateAbstractAttachments(?,?,?,?,?)");
    $query->bind_param("ibssi", $abstractID, null, $name, $type, $size);
    foreach (str_split($attachment, 10240) as $chunk) {
        $query->send_long_data(1, $chunk);
    }
    $query->execute();
    $query->close();
```

(Full disclosure, I've never used `send_long_data()` before. I have always stored files in the filesystem and would advise doing the same!)

Finally, every database function you perform – opening a connection, preparing a statement, binding parameters, and executing a statement – should have its result [checked for errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Even if there are no errors, MySQL can still produce [non-fatal warnings](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-warnings.php) which can result in things like bad values not being inserted.

Comment: I changed the SQL statement from a prepared to a explicit statement, and it now works. So I suspect that my procedure doesn't like the BLOB. Any ideas what the procedure could be doing?

Comment: I've found out the problem. It turns out that it doesn't like BLOB as a parameter type for prepared statements. When I changed it into a string, it accepted it and now displays correctly in the table. So that is strange.